# How to bootstrap a MIPS NetBSD iso in qemu?

Tags: qemu, netbsd

I'm trying to bootstrap a NetBSD 4.0 iso in qemu, but am not having much luck.  My host computer is running OS X, and I successfully installed qemu with homebrew, but have been unable to bootstrap the NetBSD 4.0 iso from here => ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-archive/NetBSD-4.0/mipsco/

Currently I'm running the following command to try and bootstrap the iso,
`qemu-system-mips -M mips -cdrom /ISO/mipscocd-4.0.iso`

It launches a new window, but there is no display output in the window.

I also tried the following,
`qemu-system-mips -M mips -cdrom /ISO/mipscocd-4.0.iso -kernel netbsd-INSTALL -hda NetBSD4.0.img`

Neither of those commands produced any results.